# Simple Spring batch project in spring source tools suits using maven

Tags: spring

I m very new in spring batch project.I m trying to create a project in spring batch framework but i don't know how to create a project in spring batch framework,so please help me regarding my problem.Firstly just tell me that how i create a simple "hello world" program using Simple Spring Batch Project in spring source tools suits using maven.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation, it looks like there is no real maven archetypes to build the skeleton of a spring batch projet. 
The documentation recommends anyway to copy samples and examples from their website to start from.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch is not trivial for the first time, then I recommend you to copy this code:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples

Then, using Eclipse open this (Maven project) and compile (mvn clean install)
Last thing (if all works ok) just run the main method, usually o Scheduler task.